# how to get call number info for outgoing and incoming calls

Tags: android

I have made a broadcast receiver and whenever an outgoing call event happens it fetches the outgoing number. Now I want to integrate it for incoming number too. I am sharing the code.

callreceiver class

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager tManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String OutgoingCallNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i("CLApp", OutgoingCallNumber);
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

error-Log :

```
06-01 10:57:36.209: E/dalvikvm(29762): Could not find class 'android.content.RestrictionsManager', referenced from method com.salesforce.androidsdk.config.RuntimeConfig.getRestrictions
06-01 10:57:36.219: E/dalvikvm(29762): Could not find class 'android.content.RestrictionsManager', referenced from method com.salesforce.androidsdk.config.RuntimeConfig.hasRestrictionsProvider
06-01 10:57:36.329: E/IMGSRV(29762): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
06-01 10:57:36.209: E/dalvikvm(29762): Could not find class 'android.content.RestrictionsManager', referenced from method com.salesforce.androidsdk.config.RuntimeConfig.getRestrictions
06-01 10:57:36.219: E/dalvikvm(29762): Could not find class 'android.content.RestrictionsManager', referenced from method com.salesforce.androidsdk.config.RuntimeConfig.hasRestrictionsProvider
 06-01 10:57:36.329: E/IMGSRV(29762): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
 06-01 10:57:36.329: E/IMGSRV(29762): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
 06-01 10:57:36.329: E/IMGSRV(29762): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
 06-01 10:57:36.329: E/IMGSRV(29762): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762): Process: io.concret.callloggerapp, PID: 29762
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver io.concret.callloggerapp.CallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2593)
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
 06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.util.Log.println_filter(Log.java:105)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:187)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at io.concret.callloggerapp.CallReceiver.onReceive(CallReceiver.java:23)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
06-01 10:57:52.709: E/AndroidRuntime(29762):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the intent received is for incoming call or outgoing call in your Receiver class

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
TelephonyManager tManager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
      // Outgoing call
      final String outgoingCallNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
      Log.i("CLApp", OutgoingCallNumber);
    }
    else {
         // Incoming call
         String incomingCallNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
         Log.i("CLApp", incomingCallnumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: The app get stopped when i make a call for a test on the device how can i check what's wrong?

Comment: it says its an androidruntime error at .......CallReceiver.onReceive (CallReceive.java:27)

Comment: Edit your post with full Logcat error message, not just one line.

Comment: hello Bidhan, somehow it have started working, i am getting the outgoing and incoming number. but it would be great to know the reason why it stopped working in the first case. Thank you for your help. I am a newbie in android.

Comment: It's okay. You probably needed to rebuild the project. If you run into any error, then the first thing you need to do is check your logcat for error messages and try to understand them by searching about them online. It's one of the best ways of learning Android development especially when you're just starting out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get incoming and outgoing call info from call logs itself.
Below code snippet will give you call logs between a range of date

```
final String SELECT = CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?" + " AND "
      + CallLog.Calls.DATE + "<?";
Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
      CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            CallLog.Calls._ID },
      SELECT,
      new String[] { String.valueOf(afterdate.getTime()),
            String.valueOf(beforeDate.getTime()) },
      CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc");

int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
   phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
   String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
   String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
   Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
   final String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
   String dir = null;
   int callTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
   final SmsDetailsPojo dataItem = new SmsDetailsPojo();
   String contactName = Util.getContactName(context, phNumber);

   dataItem.setContactNum(phNumber);
   dataItem.setContactName(contactName);
   dataItem.setSmsCount(callDuration);


   arrContactDetails.add(dataItem);
}



e
```